# Virtualenv with pyspark 3.0 and Python 3.7.8

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, virtualenv

I am trying to submit a pyspark job using a virtual environment with Spark 3.0 and Python 3.7.8.

This is working :

```
pyspark \
> --conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.enabled=true \
> --conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.type=native \
> --conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.bin.path=/usr/bin/virtualenv
```

20/10/09 16:38:06 INFO VirtualEnvFactory: Start to setup virtualenv...
20/10/09 16:38:06 INFO VirtualEnvFactory: Running command:/usr/bin/virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 --system-site-packages /tmp/1602261486643-0
20/10/09 16:38:08 INFO VirtualEnvFactory: virtualenv is created at /tmp/1602261486643-0/bin/python

but when I submit a job with spark-submit

with these options:

```
conf = SparkConf().setAll(
  [
              ("spark.pyspark.virtualenv.enabled", "true"),
              ("spark.pyspark.virtualenv.type", "native"),
              ("spark.pyspark.virtualenv.bin.path", "/usr/bin/virtualenv")
  ]
)
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

the job does not use virtualenv and when I am trying to install a python packages, it tries to install in the location :
Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/scipy-1.5.2.dist-info'

rather than the tmp directory as with pyspark.

The same job used to work well in Spark 2.4.

Any idea why virtualenv works with pyspark but not spark-submit in Spark 3.0 ?

Thank you for your help,

Cheers,

Bertrand